# how to add information to json using Python in fast way

Tags: python, json, csv, pandas

I have geojson file that contains places. where "'parking': 0 " all the time.

```
'type': 'Feature', 
'properties': {
 ...// Other fields
'latitude': -74.0121613846062,
'longitude': 40.7043040747924,
'parking': 0 }
```

I would like to update it from another csv file data set.

```
-------------------------------------------
 latitude    + Longitude + Possible_parking 
-------------------------------------------
-74.012161      40.804        -1
```

-1: Impossible to park

1: Possible Parking

I would like to update the geojson file.

```
data = pd.read_csv("data/_all.csv")

geojson_in = open('data/input.json', 'r')
tracts_geojson = json.load(geojson_in)
geojson_in.close()


# For each record in the geojson file, add location information
for i, r in enumerate(tracts_geojson['features']):
    for x in range(len(data.latitude.values)):
        if ((r['properties']['latitude']==data["latitude"][x]) and (r['properties']['longitude']== data["longitude"][x])):
            r['properties']['parking'] = str(data['Possible_parking'][x])
```

The problem with script I am using is that it takes so long time (+24 hours now). 
I don't wanna convert csv file to json directly, 'cause input.json contains other information that I can't find in CSV file.

Is there any pythonic way to do this faster ?

Comment: How big is the CSV file?

Comment: Size of CSV file is: 600Mb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looping through your whole parking CSV rows for each feature in the JSON file; this is a N * M loop; a 600MB CSV file contains roughly 30 million parking space entries (at roughly 21 bytes per row), and you are looping through all 30 million *per feature*.

You want to load the whole CSV file into a dictionary:

```
import csv

with open(("data/_all.csv", 'rb') as incsv:
    reader = csv.reader(incsv)
    next(reader, None)  # skip presumed header
    parking = {(lat, long): park for lat, long, park in reader}
```

Use this instead of looping over the whole dataset for each JSON entry:

```
for feat in tracts_geojson['features']:
    lat, long = feat['properties']['latitude'], feat['properties']['longitude']
    if (lat, long) in parking:
        feat['properties']['parking'] = parking[lat, long]
```

Lookups in a dictionary take constant time; instead of 30 million loops per feature you now use one straight-forward lookup per feature.

Comment: The beauty of hash(ing).

Comment: Do you happen to know how a dictionary comprehension will perform in terms of the dict having to be resized? Does it allocate the dict's size once, based on the iterable's length, or will it be resized over and over again before it gets 2/3 full?

Comment: @LukasGraf: It'll resize dynamically as if you added items one by one.

Comment: @LukasGraf: the OPCODES used do allow for a pre-size, but the dynamic nature of Python doesn't allow for predicting the size up front here. So `BUILD_MAP 0` is done (create empty dictionary, not presized), then each iteration `MAP_ADD` is executed, which is basically a `dict.__setitem__()` call.

Comment: Thanks! I re-wrote the first part using pandas/zip to be more pythonic (UPDATE).

Comment: @user3378649: there is little point in using Pandas here then re-zip the data to fit the dictionary. Using the stdlib `csv` module here directly is far more efficient.

Comment: @user3378649: my apologies, I forgot to remove the `enumerate()` call in my version.